# How to move sidebar menu to top in CP

Tags: plugins, control-panel

I've seen some Craft CPs that display the sidebar menu horizontally in the top of the browser as a header.  Does anyone know how this is done? Is there a plugin? I think this would be useful for clients using a smaller monitor, particularly when using live preview.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could pull it off with some [CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss)/[JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) hackery, but it'd be pretty sketchy.

The navigation bar used to be at the top of the Control Panel up until Craft 2.5 came out.  The screenshots you're seeing are probably of the older versions of Craft.